# Clickonce manifest postactions

Tags: c#, vsto, clickonce, manifest

I have vsto application using ClickOnce, and using post-deployment action, whitch I done by

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772100.aspx 
Put the document of a solution onto the end user's computer (document-level customizations only)

```
<vstav3:postActions>
  <vstav3:postAction>
    <vstav3:entryPoint class="ClickOnceLibrary.ClickOnceLibrary">
      <assemblyIdentity name="ClickOnceLibrary"
                    version="1.2.0.8" language="neutral"
                    processorArchitecture="msil" />
    </vstav3:entryPoint>
  </vstav3:postAction>
</vstav3:postActions>
```

> mage -sign Foo.dll.manifest -certfile soft_certificate.pfx -pwd bar
>
> mage -update Foo.vsto -appmanifest "Application Files\Foo_1_2_0_8\Foo.dll.manifest" -certfile "Application Files\Foo_1_2_0_8\soft_certificate.pfx" -pwd bar

so after signing clickonce manifest with Mage: Publisher,support url, product name(stats using project name) etc. change

My question, is there a way too automatically add postActions so I wouldn't need to edit manifest manually, or maybe you know what could be the problem to manifest not reading info correctly after using mage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well coulnd't really find how to do it automatically, but when signing with mage using options work...

```
mage -sign Foo.dll.manifest -certfile soft_certificate.pfx -pwd bar -s "supporturl" -pub "publisher"
mage -update Foo.vsto -appmanifest "Application Files\Foo_1_2_0_8\Foo.dll.manifest" -certfile "Application Files\Foo_1_2_0_8\soft_certificate.pfx" -pwd bar -s "supporturl" -pub "publisher"
```